# How to attach rebar to a sheet of metal?

Tags: metal, rebar

I need to use some rebar, driven into the ground, to support a metal sheet:

```
 ______________________________________________________________
|                                                              | <-- thin aluminum sheet
|        ||                         ||                         |
|        ||                         || <--rebar next to sheet metal
|        ||                         ||                         |
|________||_________________________||_________________________|~~~~~~~~~ <-- ground
         ||                         ||
         \| <--rebar underground    \|
```

What is a good, strong way to affix the rebar to the sheet metal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intentions aren't entirely clear, but here are some general ideas:

- [U-bolt clamps](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/ff6b147c-619c-460f-bf1d-635b95beea2b/svn/national-hardware-u-bolts-n222-133-64_1000.jpg) through holes in the sheet and around the bar
- [Hose clamps](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/f2d660e7-e21b-4c36-abb6-c8971b37eaa0/svn/everbilt-repair-clamps-6712595-64_1000.jpg) through slots in the sheet and around the bar
- Wire through holes in the sheet and around the bar
- A friend with a welder (though the dissimilar metals make this challenging)
- Bolts through the rebar and the sheet
- Screws through the sheet and into the rebar
- Wire around the bar from below the sheet to above

Comment: How does a bolt go through rebar?

Comment: Right behind a drill bit. Rebar is quite soft.